# How to do overlapping styles with Styled Components React?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am new to **React with Styled Components** and have run into the following issue:

If I have 10 Styled Components and each of them have the property: `background-color: green;`, **do I have to write that for each Styled Component**? Or is there some way to specify that for all? Thanks.

Comment: Styled components supports theming, see: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: Use [this](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css)

Comment: @FRMR can this be used for things other than color? For example: `display: flex;`?

Comment: Yes, you can pass variables to represent any CSS value you want.

Comment: @FRMR I see, but just to confirm, I would still have to specify the key in each Styled Component, for example: `background-color: ${props => props.theme.main}` for each one.

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt Because I am new to this, I don't really understand the example code. Is `complexMixin` able to be applied to any Styled Component?

Comment: @NickSmith See my answer for detailed descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish shared styles.

1. You can further style existing styled components with the [`styled`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#styled) function, so first declaring a basic styled component with shared styles and defining more specially styled components using it:

   ```
   import styled from 'styled-components';

   const Base = styled.div`
     background-color: green;
   `;

   const StyledComp1 = styled(Base)`
     display: flex;
   `;

   const StyledComp2 = styled(Base)`
     display: block;
   `;
   ```
2. You can use the styled-components [`css`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) utility function:

   ```
   import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

   const sharedStyles = css`
     background-color: green;
   `;

   const StyledComp1 = styled.div`
     ${sharedStyles};
     display: flex;
   `;

   const StyledComp2 = styled.div`
     ${sharedStyles};
     display: block;
   `;
   ```

Comment: Ohhhh! This is exactly what I am looking for. Which one is recommended? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Use #1, if you don't want to share styles between different types of elements (div, p, span, etc.). If you want to, then use #2.

Comment: Right, that makes sense! Really appreciate the help. Btw, I'm wondering if you know of any good React + Styled Components example projects that follow best coding practices. Maybe any open source companies etc?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. I used styled-components heavily in the past, but it was all self-trained and I actually don't remember having seen any open source code using styled-components.

Comment: I see - do you think that would that be appropriate to post here? Regardless, thanks so much!!

Comment: Oh, you mean posting a new question asking for those example projects, I just saw it. Yeah, seems like it is absolutely appropriate, you already got some upvotes! Good luck!